# Can't recover Kingston SSD - no partitions, no data

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, data-recovery, ssd

I had a disk failure before getting around to backing up a lot of notes and configs, updated pw file etc. My main work was saved/on a different disk, thankfully, so this hasn't been a "pay anything for recovery" situation, but I figured I could still retrieve the data from a different/new system and that it was useful enough to keep trying.

I've tried a lot of stuff since and actually nothing has worked. I tried to do it all in read-only, and tried working on the image, but with I/O errors it has been tough. I can't seem to find anyone with a similar SSD issue anywhere online, so I figured someone here might have come across this before.

### Actions taken

Here's a rough list of what I've run through from my notes of a couple of weeks back:

- `testdisk` (no partitions, error `no endmark 0xAA55` hang at 0% scan, 3/29184)
- `photorec` (no partitions show up, but the drive can be selected and scanned - to no avail)
- `fsck` (no recognized fs on disk)
- `gparted` partition recovery - not possible
- `e2fsck` superblock recovery listing and using as starting point
- `chkdsk` from a win10 laptop, `chkdsk E: /F /R` iirc as well as `mountvol` if that's the right command - only mountvol showed what appeared to be boot partition full of win files. Not sure how that happened as I ran Debian/grub on the drive, but could be from previous use. Slightly concerned chkdsk wrote something to the drive, but didn't output that it had anywhere, I just read somewhere that it can do (after I did it).
- `recuva` on win10 laptop, nothing found except the same volume from mountvol.
- `ddrescue` image of the drive, 240GB in size
- `DMDE` - the image did scan OK, but nothing found, the original drive itself didn't scan, halting at 61448 asking for retry/ignore/abort etc. giving I/O errors. Reports it as an ASMedia AS2105.

#### The drive

Kingston 240 GB SSD ASMT2105 - RMA'd with Kingston and they exchanged, no questions asked, keep the old drive. Many reports of firmware failures online, with some Russian recovery software available but not for data, just to restore the drive. Wonder if they know what the fault is, because they asked me for the specific type/batch of that drive. Was showing up in testdisk/photorec as the `SATAFIRM S11`, for which I found references to drives being [relabelled as "phison"](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/kingston-satafirm-s11-fix.3489081/) somehow.

#### Potential cause

The week before the failure I was comparing ripgrep to vim search on a > 12GB file on a separate drive, but decided to kill the process impatiently. This caused the disk space on the drive holding the file (separate nvme) to be misreported as ~0. The file I was working on wasn't on the faulty drive, but perhaps the pagefile was, I'm not 100% sure of how I'd set it up now. Both drives seemed OK after a restart at some point. I actually doubt it was this, but it did happen so might be worth noting. No idea what could have caused it otherwise. It was running with under 10-20GB free space, if something could have pushed it over the edge to corrupt it. No idea!

Anyone here have *any* idea of what could possibly still be done to recover the data? Happy to pastebin logs or output from any other tools.

TIA.

EDIT: Here's what r-studio (demo version) is showing when I connect the drive:

[image: r-studio view of the failed drive]

Comment: No partition table?  Can't read any data from it?   "It's dead, Jim"

Comment: Why both `e2fsck` (for an extN filesystem) and `CHKDSK` (for NTFS or FAT32 filesystems)? What partitions and filesystems do you think you should have on this disk?

Comment: @roaima I wasn't sure which filesystem I was running tbh. Should have been ext4 but various tools were reporting various things. It seemed to still have an old boot partition from Win on there that could have caused that? Probably a moot point in either case?

Comment: @cas Yeah, dead as a dodo. But does that include actual chances of recovery of anything? Buddy had a drive fail the week before it happened to me. "I must back up the bits I still need to" I said to myself, with my external Attic backup drive sitting next to me the whole time.

Comment: UPDATE: R-Studio demo version gave this: `Read disk ASMedia AS2105 at position 29630464 failed after 1 attempts. Input/output error`

Comment: Offhand, it sounds like a disk failure, possibly a critical one involving the partition tables, and/or file system data,  and/or the drive controller failing and unable to map the physical drive to the logical sectors needed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `foremost` on a unix system. It will read the stream os bytes and try to get some files based on header and magic numbers.

You can try this command:

```
foremost -i file240G.dump -o directory/
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I ran it this morning and it gave `0 files extracted` unfortunately. Maybe carving is one way forward though.